# What is the maximum number of spaces on Sierra?

Tags: macos, spaces

My MacBook runs Sierra 10.12.4 and I have 16 spaces, but there appears to be no way to get more. I find 16 spaces too few. Is 16 the absolute maximum or can I get more? If so how?

Comment: See this https://superuser.com/questions/893258/how-to-remove-the-limit-of-how-many-desktop-spaces-can-be-opened-in-mission-cont

Answer (score 2):

Officially, 16 is the limit. A workaround to create more (which may be fixed later) is to enable ‘Displays have separate Spaces’ in Mission Control preference pane, then create spaces on an external display and disconnect the display, which moves the Spaces to the primary display.